# How to convert response of post request to bool in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an endpoint in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<bool> CheckStatus([FromBody] StatusModel model)
{
...code ommited
return true;
}
```

And I call this endpoint from other place in code like this:

```
await client.PostAsync('/CheckStatus', payloayd)
```

How can I retrive a bool value from this request?

Comment: ... Set a variable to the result of `await client.PostAsync(url, payloayd)` and parse it as a `bool`?

Comment: How is PostAsync connected to CheckStatus?

Comment: PostAsync calls CheckStatus endpoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Newtonsoft.Json, you can read the response of the request and parse it into a bool.

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public async Task<bool> GetBooleanAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var data = new { };
            var url = "my site url";

            var payload = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var req = await client.PostAsync(url, payload);
            var response = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(response);
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

Looking back on this from a few years on, this can be simplified without the use of Newtonsoft.Json to read the response, by simply parsing the string data to a boolean.

```
public async Task<bool> GetBooleanAsync()
{
    var data = new { };
    var url = "my site url";

    var payload = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    using var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, payload);
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Boolean.Parse(data);
}
```

However, if your boolean value is returned in a JSON object, then Newtonsoft.Json could be used to read that value.

Comment: For the updated response, I believe the return statement should be 'Boolean.Parse' instead

Comment: @RajeevPande good spot, cheers :)